# Need help related async functions execution flow (await, promises, node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I will appreciate if you help me with the following case:

Given function:

```
async function getAllProductsData() {
  try {
    allProductsInfo = await getDataFromUri(cpCampaignsLink);
    allProductsInfo = await getCpCampaignsIdsAndNamesData(allProductsInfo);
    await Promise.all(allProductsInfo.map(async (item) => {
      item.images = await getProductsOfCampaign(item.id);
    }));
    allProductsInfo = JSON.stringify(allProductsInfo);
    console.log(allProductsInfo);
    return allProductsInfo;
  } catch(err) {
    handleErr(err);
  }
}
```

That function is fired when server is started and it gathers campaigns information from other site: gets data(getDataFromUri()), then extracts from data name and id(getCpCampaignsIdsAndNamesData()), then gets products images for each campaign (getProductsOfCampaign());

I have also express.app with following piece of code:

```
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
  if (allProductsInfo.length === undefined) {
    console.log('Pending...');
    allProductsInfo = await getAllProductsData();
  }
  res.status(200).send(allProductsInfo);
});
```

Problem description:

1. Launch server, wait few seconds until getAllProductsData() gets executed, do '/products' GET request, all works great!
2. Launch server and IMMEDIATELY fire '/products' GET request' (for that purpose I added IF with console.log('Pending...') expression), I get corrupted result back: it contains all campaigns names, ids, but NO images arrays.

   - [{"id":"1111","name":"Some name"},{"id":"2222","name":"Some other name"}],
     while I was expecting
   - [{"id":"1111","name":"Some name","images":["URI","URI"...]}...]

I will highly appreciate your help about:

- Explaining the flow of what is happening with async execution, and why the result is being sent without waiting for images arrays to be added to object?
- If you know some useful articles/specs part covering my topic, I will be thankful for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a huge issue with using a global variable `allProductsInfo`, and then firing multiple concurrent functions that use it asynchronously. This creates race conditions of all kinds, and you have to consider yourself *lucky* that you got *only* not images data.

You can easily solve this by making `allProductsInfo` a local variable, or at least not use it to store the intermediate results from `getDataFromUri` and `getCpCampaignsIdsAndNamesData` - use different (local!) variables for those.

However, even if you do that, you're potentially firing `getAllProductsData` multiple times, which should not lead to errors but is still inefficient. It's much easier to store a promise in the global variable, initialise this *once* with a single call to the info gathering procedure, and just to await it every time - which won't be noticeable when it's already fulfilled.

```
async function getAllProductsData() {
  const data = await getDataFromUri(cpCampaignsLink);
  const allProductsInfo = await getCpCampaignsIdsAndNamesData(allProductsInfo);
  await Promise.all(allProductsInfo.map(async (item) => {
    item.images = await getProductsOfCampaign(item.id);
  }));
  console.log(allProductsInfo);
  return JSON.stringify(allProductsInfo);
}

const productDataPromise = getAllProductsData();
productDataPromise.catch(handleErr);
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(await productDataPromise);
});
```

Of course you might also want to start your server (or add the `/products` route to it) only after the data is loaded, and simply serve status 500 until then. Also you should consider what happens when the route is hit after the promise is rejected - not sure what `handleErr` does.